No users are listed on any volumes, when resetting password, in internet recovery mode. Macbook has broken keyboard topcase with stuck modifier keys
My password won't work. I am dyslexic. I have a Macbook Retina 12". It has a broken 'top case' which means different combinations of modifier keys are regularly enabled, namley the shift key. I have adopted workarounds and software utilities to use it for the past few years. (i.e. I usually hold down the Option key to bypass safe mode login at startup)
Filevault is not enabled. I have double checked this using diskutil apfs list
Currently my login password is not recognised. This may be because of capitalisation, but I have tried external keyboards and lots of messing around, and have decided to reset the password after weeks of trying things.
I can boot into internet recovery mode only. (local recovery mode is inaccessible to me because of keys stuck on)
In internet recovery mode, in Terminal, I run RESETPASSWORD (caps seems to be accepted in terminal) and the password reset tool opens.
I can see 7 (seven) volumes, and when I select all/any of them, and press 'next' the message: 'There are no users on this volume to reset password for' is displayed.
Any help appriciated with next steps!
I am unable to run disk repair also.
The volumes are:
VM,
Preboot,
transfere (spelled incorrectly),
Recovery,
Update,
Update,
bedo - Data,

Do you have all your data backed up? Realistically, you need to fix the keyboard before anything else, in order to use this Mac. (Or see if you can disconnect it.) Ideally, you need another Mac.

Welcome to Ask Different. Which version of macOS is your Mac running? Out of curiosity, in recovery mode, if you type your password in Terminal, does it match what you would expect it to be?

@benwiggy - Yes, i have a time machine backup from July, nothing since. I have a second hand M1 Studio and i am in the processs of moving data from all the other outdated machines, a 2009 macbook pro, a working 3,1 MacPro ect. And then I will fix the keyboard. Thanks for the idea to disconnect it. It's a chip that is faulty, but it effects external keyboards connected too sadly. Thankyou for the suggestions. Greatly apriciated.

@jaume - Terminal in recovery mode with SW_VERS is 10.12.6 build 16G29. I have failed to find a prompt to try my password! Typing SUDO (caps is my only option) says command not found. Any suggetions? Thank you for the comments, greatly apriciated.

Thank you. I'd strongly recommend that you stop using the built-in keyboard and switch to an external one. The stuck shift key won't affect the external keyboard after the system has started up and you will be able to work normally and run Terminal commands without issues (with a few exceptions, most commands  are lowercase). My question whether you could type your password in Terminal was not related to sudo but simply about finding out whether your built-in keyboard supports the string of characters in your password. That shouldn't be an issue if you use an external keyboard, though.

@jaume As far as i can tell the stuck shift key is a chip problem, that then also effects external keyboards. They do not help. My initial question/inquirey is why there are no users listed on any drive table partition.  I did understand you wnated me to type my password into terminal. I thought sudo commands ofetn require passwords? Can you recomend a comand that illisits a password request?  I chose a password that was all upper case letters but not numbers so that I could type regardless of shift keys. But this has stoped working for some reason. So I'm looking to reset it. Thanks again.

If you're just trying to move your data from this Mac to a Studio, I would just use your backup data. Or use Target Disk mode to see what you can recover.  Then hand in the Mac to an Apple Store for recycling.

I see, I was hoping an external keyboard would work so that you can run Terminal commands. To your question about a command that asks for a password, I can only think of sudo. As to why there are no users listed when you select any partition, I don't know but I'm afraid there's a bigger underlying problem and you may need to reinstall the OS. According to Apple, there are several ways to reset a password: pressing a question mark next to the password field in the login window, using your Apple ID or running resetpassword. Do you have an Apple ID or see a question mark in the login window?

@benwiggy I can't login to target disk mode because the modifier keys are stuck on. I've searched for a terminal comand, to restart into target disk mode from recovery mode. To no avail. I have discoverd my backup is for another macbook. I'm in a rescue mentality  now.

@jaume Thanks for the info on password resetting. There is no question mark in the login fiel, and i think this may be because i never logged into my apple ID systemwide on this laptop. i do apriciate the help form you both. Target disk mode would be very useful now
